# What are reagents for?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I'm playing a Sorcerer through the original official campaign and I've been picking up various items that seem initially worthless but look like they should have some uses:

Dragon Blood, Special Holy Water, Firebeetle Belly, Skeleton Knuckle, and others.

In a FAQ, I read they're reagents, but it didn't say how, when or where they can be used.

I have just reached the second chapter and I'd rather keep spoilers to a minimum. Can I expect these items to become useful in this chapter, or only later? Will it be obvious when they become useful?

Answer (score 3):

They're used in the games crafting system.

Throughout the campaign, you'll come across a few NPC's that will offer to create upgraded equipment for you. They'll generally need one item of this sort, along with a magic weapon to improve.

For example, your Dragon Blood can be combined with a Rapier to make a Namarra Rapier that puts enemies to sleep.

Specifically, in Chapter 1, you'll want to go to the back room of Marrok's forge, at The Shining Knight Arms & Armor, in the City Core area. Later, at Beorunna's Well, Barun Silverblade will provide similar services, but yielding better items. There are also a number of Arcane devices or alchemical contraptions of various sorts, into which you can place a combination of reagents to yield interesting items. You'll generally find a recipe book nearby each of them. If you'd like to look them all up, the [Reference Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/188666-neverwinter-nights/faqs/18545) hosted at GameFAQs - specifically section `(C) Custom Items` - lists them all quite neatly. The NWN wiki is, in my experience, a bit less helpful for this stuff, as it tends to not have particularly detailed information about the campaigns.

They're also used in a variety of recipes which you can learn through various crafting skills and feats. Again, to use the example of 'Dragon Blood', it can be used to scribe scrolls of Time Stop Harm, and True Seeing with the appropriate feat, once you know the spell.

Answer (score 1):

These items are used to craft various items. Whether you'll be able to use them depends on how you allocate your skill points - if your craft trap skill stays at 0, you won't be able to use skeleton knuckles to make negative energy traps, for example. You can look up what each reagent is used for and skill requirements on [NWN Wikia](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page).